# How to use grep to retrieve a string within a line

Tags: macos, unix, grep

MacOS, Unix

I'm trying to use grep to isolate a particular ID within a line as follows:

```
# STOCKHOLM 1.0

#=GS WP_002089484.1/1-154 DE [subseq from] MULTISPECIES: AAC(3)-I family aminoglycoside 3-N-acetyltransferase [Proteobacteria]

WP_002089484.1/1-154 MGIIRTCRLGPDQVKSMRAALDLFGREFGDVATYSQHQPDSDYLGNLLRSKTFIALAAFDQEAVVGALAAYVLPKFEQARSEIYIYDLAVSGEHRRQGIATALINLLKHEANALGAYVIYVQADYGDDPAVALYTKLGIREEVMHFDIDPSTAT
#=GR WP_002089484.1/1-154 PP 9*******************************************************************************************************************************************************98
#=GC PP_cons                 9*******************************************************************************************************************************************************98
#=GC RF                      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
//
```

I just want to isolate the part that says WP_002089484.1, but I have to do this for many files, where the ID always starts with "WP_" and always ends with ".1". And I just want unique occurrences from each file.

I tried something like:

```
grep -o "WP_.\{0,11\}" *.sto >> ProtID
```

but ProtID still has all the information from the original file.

Comment: When I ran your test file and grep command, ProtID had 3 lines, all with just `WP_002089484.1`. It seems like this is pretty much what you want, except for duplicates. What do you mean by "ProtID still has all the information from the original file?" Since you only append to ProtID is it possible you never deleted this file during development and old results lingered?

Comment: Ah, I made a mistake, I didn't delete the previous file, so  it was appending to the already existing file, so the only issue was the duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just unique occurrences from each file, the following command should help you:

```
grep  -o  "WP_.\{0,11\}" *.sto | sort | uniq
```

The output will be:

```
file1.sto:WP_002089484.1
file2.sto:WP_002089484.1
```

And if you want to remove the file name from the result:

```
grep  -o  "WP_.\{0,11\}" *.sto | sort | uniq  | grep -o "WP_.\{0,11\}"
```

In this case, the output will be:

```
WP_002089484.1
WP_002089484.1
```